# How to make a palette-like menu using swing?

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a menu with tabs which displays some options like the palette used by Window Builder of Eclipse when I click in a tab.
I need something similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Why can't you adapt the approach used in Eclipse or NetBeans?

Comment: I don't know which component is being used in Eclipse nor how it's implemented.

Comment: Start with [*How to Use Lists*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess swing has no element like this. But you could take a look at the Standard Widget Toolkit (SWT) which is maintained by the Eclipse Foundation. It includes a widget called ExpandBar, which is probably what you are searching for. Documentation and API found
[here](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/).
[image: SWT ExpandBar]